# Last access of a DB in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have "inherited" a collection of Mysql DBs (~900) and I would like to know which of them are actually being used. I looked around and I can find some commands like:

```
SELECT from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MAX(UPDATE_TIME))) as last_update FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='MY_DB' GROUP BY TABLE_SCHEMA;
```

but this does not really tell me if MY_DB is being accessed by some web service or users, right? It only informs about when it was last updated, unless I got it wrong. If so, is there a more accurate way to find out the last access of a DB?

Thank you!

Comment: enable general query log and then you can monitor it. Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html

Comment: Yes but, if this is not enabled by now, will I have retrospective info? Or it counts AFTER I enable it?

Comment: No, it will not have retrospective info. Also, you will need to setup some auto-cleanup for the logs also (after getting relevant summary points out of it); otherwise it gets big pretty fast